Visual Studio 2022 not generating code from comment with GitHub Copilot
I have installed GitHub Copilot from Visual Studio extensions

It works fine for autocompletes

But when I add a commented line asking for some implementation and press enter, there is no code suggested. Is there a way to "activate" this feature?

I'm using .NET 8.0 and the version of my VisualStudio is 17.8.2

Try telling it what to do without the "Create code do" bit. That much is implied. I have also noticed that copilot prefers to leave a line after the comment before giving code completions.

Thanks, I just type "Print hello world in console" and it works fine
